# How to copy a image to a Directory in C language

Tags: c, image, directory, copy

I was trying to copy a image file using file open and write file method, but enable to achieve the image... So please help me out with the code along with the header file required.

```
   char ch, source_file[20], target_file[20];
   FILE *source, *target;
   source = fopen("Source", "r");
   if( source == NULL )
   {
   printf("Press any key to exit...\n");
   }
   target = fopen("Destination", "w");
   if( target == NULL )
   {
   fclose(source);
   }

   while( ( ch = fgetc(source) ) != EOF )
   fputc(ch, target);

   printf("File copied successfully.\n");

   fclose(source);
   fclose(target);
```

I tried This....

Comment: So your question is what?

Comment: you should start the code, then we have a look at it.

Comment: You need `<stdio.h>`; you might use `fread()` and `fwrite()`; you will use `fopen()`; you will probably use `b` as one of the flags in the open call.

Comment: Edit your code into the question, in a properly formatted format, please (no tabs; indented).  Convert to code by selecting the formatted code and pressing the **`{}`** button above the edit box.

Comment: use `int ch` and filemode "rb", "wb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
FILE *source, *target;
int i;
source = fopen("Source", "rb"); 

if( source == NULL ) { printf("Press any key to exit...\n");} //exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 

fseek(source, 0, SEEK_END);
int length = ftell(source);

fseek(source, 0, SEEK_SET);
target = fopen("Destination", "wb"); 

if( target == NULL ) { fclose(source); } //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    fputc(fgetc(source), target);
}

printf("File copied successfully.\n"); 
fclose(source); 
fclose(target);
```

valter